# ARM assembly - access parameter vs return value?

Tags: c++, assembly, cpu-registers, arm64, calling-convention

I have a function prototype `int Palindrome(const char *c_style_string);`

In ARM v8 assembly, I believe that the parameter is stored in register w0. However, isn't this also the register that `ret` outputs the value of?

If so, what do I need to do so that values do not get overwritten? I was thinking something like `mov w0, w1` at the beginning of my code so that I refer to c_style_string as w1 whenever I parse through it, and then edit w0 to store an int...would this be right?

Thank you!

Comment: BTW, register selection for function calls is a compiler decision, not an assembly language issue.  The compiler may pass a parameter in R8.

Comment: ARM syntax is `mnemonic  dst, src`, so  you want `mov w1, w0` to make a copy of `w0` (your first arg).

Comment: there is no reason why the output cannot overwrite an input register.  The pointer that comes into the function is pass by reference but it is a copy of the address put there just for that function, if that function calls another function it will also overwrite that parameter register and on and on, and the returns of all nested functions will overwrite on the way back up.  the stack can be used or if the parameter is not needed then simply overwrite.

Comment: AT&T syntax is the only syntax I know that puts dest at the end

Comment: @phuclv: m68k syntax puts the dst last, too.  And AT&T syntax was inspired by PDP-11 syntax which also does that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to write your assembly code in compliance with the [ABI for ARM 64-bit Architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch09s01s01.html). 
 
In the example above, you could keep the address for c_style_string in a 'Callee-saved' register (X19-X29)', and copy it to x0/w0 every time you are calling a Palindrome() - I am assuming here Palindrome() is a C function, and is therefore itself compliant with the ARCH 64-bit ABI. 
A desirable side-effect would be that your C code could call always your assembly code, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your best solution is to write the C function, or minimal function, then tell the compiler to output the assembly language.  This will show the calling interface for functions.

You could also look up the register passing convention in your compiler's documentation.

If you want to preserve register values, you should use the PUSH instruction (or it's equivalent, depending on ARM mode or Thumb mode).  Also remember to POP the registers before the end of the function.